# How to send env vars to Cypress using GitHub action?

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, cypress, github-actions, e2e

I'm trying to run my Cypress tests using a GitHub action, but can't figure out how to send in environment variables to Cypress to override my local config.

Currently I have the baseUrl set to https://localhost:3000 but want to send in another URL when running in my dev environment. I also would like to send in a header (token) that is used in a beforeEach function so that all my requests are allowed through to my dev environment.

I have tried both using process.env.CYPRESS_XYZ and Cypress.env('XYZ') with no success. And also tried to set the `config: baseUrl=https://xyz` in the yaml-file under the `with:` section.

The setup works when I run it locally, so only having these issues when trying to set the new baseUrl for my dev env.

Any ideas how I can get my BASE_URL and DEV_TOKEN from my workflow into my Cypress config?

cypress.config.ts

```
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
import createEsbuildPlugin from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild';
import createBundler from '@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor';
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig({
  blockHosts: [
    '*.googletagmanager.com',
    '*.google-analytics.com',
  ],
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: process.env.CYPRESS_BASE_URL || 'https://localhost:3000',
    experimentalRunAllSpecs: true,
    async setupNodeEvents(
      on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions,
    ): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        }),
      );

      on('after:spec', async (_, results) => {
        if (results && results.video) {
          // Do we have failures for any retry attempts?
          const failures = results.tests?.some((test) =>
            test.attempts.some((attempt) => attempt?.state === 'failed'),
          );
          if (!failures) {
            // delete the video if the spec passed and no tests retried
            fs.unlink(results.video, (err) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              return;
            });
          }
        }
      });

      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },
    specPattern: '**/*.feature',
  },
  env: {
    login_email: 'user@test.com',
    login_password: 'test123!',
  },
  projectId: 'xxxxx',
  screenshotsFolder: './cypress/screenshots',
  video: false,
  videosFolder: './cypress/videos',
  viewportHeight: 768,
  viewportWidth: 1024,
});
```

e2e.ts

```
import './commands';

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  return false;
});

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept(`${Cypress.config('baseUrl')}**`, req => {
      req.headers['dev_token'] = Cypress.env('DEV_TOKEN')
  });
});
```

e2e.yaml

```
name: e2e tests

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      E2E_BASE_URL:
        type: string
        description: Cypress target URL
        default: false
        required: false
    secrets:
      CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY:
        required: true
      DEV_TOKEN:
        required: true

jobs:
  e2e-test:
    name: Cypress run
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        containers: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          browser: chrome
          record: true
          parallel: true
        env:
          DEV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEV_TOKEN }}
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ inputs.E2E_BASE_URL }}
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

error message in the workflow action

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > https://localhost:3000

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

We will try connecting to it 3 more times...
We will try connecting to it 2 more times...
We will try connecting to it 1 more time...

Cypress failed to verify that your server is running.
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to get it to work using the config parameter, updating the setup like this:

cypress.config.ts

```
...
e2e: {
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000',
  experimentalRunAllSpecs: true,
...
```

e2e.yaml

```
...
- name: Cypress run
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
    with:
      browser: chrome
      record: true
      parallel: true
      config: baseUrl=${{ inputs.E2E_BASE_URL }}
...
```

I must have missed something when I tried it the first time, I assume the way I was doing it in the initial example above should work as well as described in one of the answers below, probably the same issue with my input in this case.

Lesson learnt (again), small typos or misses cost a lot of time and frustration...

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this in my project for usernames, works analogously for any kind of variable:

1. You first define the Actions secrets via the GitHub interface
2. Always start with **CYPRESS_** and remember that this will be truncated
3. Then do a step in the workflow yml:

   ```
   - name: set approx
     run: echo "CYPRESS_AUTOMATED_TESTS_USERNAME1=${{secrets.CYPRESS_AUTOMATED_TESTS_USERNAME1}}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
   ```
4. Then simply use it directly in the test using Cypress.env("AUTOMATED_TESTS_USERNAME1"),

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMPyLi8x6eo) helped me back in the days.